# shiny reactive if statement giving a "[1]" in output. how to remove this?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a shiny server code in which i have a for loop to check whether user entered 9 or nothing. But whenever user enters 9 or nothing i will get an output containing [1] aswell as ""

if i enter nothing output is

```
[1]""
```

if i enter 9 the output is

```
[1]"You are not working good"
```

how to avoid this [1] as well as double quotes?

below is my server.R code

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$name <- renderText({input$name})


output$whrs<-renderPrint({
if (input$whrs == "") {
  ""
} else  
if(input$whrs == 9)  {
  "You are not working good"
 }
  })

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should keep you going:

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$whrs<-renderText({
    if (input$text == "") {
      ""
    } else  
      if(input$text == 9)  {
        "You are not working good"
      }
  })

}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    ),
    mainPanel(selectInput("text","Enter text",choices=c("","1","9")),
              textOutput("whrs"))
  )
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You have not provided full code, and you had some faults in the one you have provided already, thats why i have just created small example that should help you further.

First of all you should use `renderText` rather then `renderPrint` --> thats why you were getting the double quotes and the `[1]`, due to the print format.

[image]

Comment: still i am getting the same output

Comment: like this --   [1] "You are not working good" how can i remove that [1] as well as "".. i just need the output as you are not working good only

Comment: Check the screenshot which i have added while using **exactly the code i have posted**....there is no [1]

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use `switch`

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    ),
    mainPanel(selectInput("text","Enter text",choices=c("","1","9")),
              textOutput("whrs"))
  )
))


server <- function(input, output) {

  res <- reactive({
    switch(input$text, 
      `""` = "",     
      `9` =  "You are not working good",
      `1`  = NA
    )

})

  output$whrs<-renderText({
         res()
    })
}



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Upon running

[image]

[image]